# Java chroot unicode support

Tags: java, linux, unicode, centos, chroot

I created a chroot jail for java on Centos 6.5 but UTF8 characters are replaced by "?":

```
chroot $J /java ClassName جدلب
```

????????

when I run java outside of jail it works fine.

```
java ClassName جدلب
```

جدلب

locale also is set to utf-8 inside jail

```
$J/bin/locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

how can I solve this issue ?

PS: chroot $J /java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"